# Running PHP - when using a node instance and port

Tags: php, ajax, linux, node.js

I'm running an application using nodejs and it's listening on port 8000, so my web url bar is ip:8000. I have an ajax call to a php file:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: './chat/store.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {message: message},
    error: function () {
        console.log('Store not working...');
    }
```

but the php won't run because were running inside the node instance, so is there anything I can do to so that php runs while accessing the ip:8000 url?

Answer (score 1):

Simple way: You could call the CMD version of php from inside node and return the value via node.

[Hard way](https://entwickler.de/webandphp/integrating-node-js-with-php-125830.html)